# Subfloors in entire house not under walls. Exposed sheetrock from under house crawlspace

Tags: subfloor

[image]

Help? So I bought this house earlier this year. My bedroom has always felt clammy and humid. After about a month or two I noticed mildew on the base boards. I pulled up the baseboards and a foot of the sheetrock to find a 2 inch gap in the subfloor to the wall. I could see directly to the dirt under my house. Upon further investigation I found all the walls to be like this. Sheetrock exposed under the house. I'm an at a loss to how in the world i am supposed to fix this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where is the house? When was it built? Was it permitted or inspected? You should probably get a general contractor to look at it or a structural engineer You have a structural problem that’s needs addressing.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. What is this picture showing?

Comment: It was inspected. Inspector said all was satisfactory. The house is in southern louisisana, built in the 40s. The picture is from under the house in the crawl space. To the right you can see a floor joist. Ubove that is a wall 2×4. To the right is the sub floor and I between is exposed sheet rock.